# Code Refactor for Current Version of Go Router

Tags: flutter, dart, gorouter

```
redirect: (GoRouterState state) {

    final loggedIn = AuthService.instance.loginInfo.isLoggedIn;

    final isLogging = state.location == '/login';

    if (!loggedIn && !isLogging) return '/login';

    if (loggedIn && isLogging) return '/stores';

    return null;
  },
```

How Can be Rewrite this Redirection Logic with Current Version of GoRouter..
I Got the Following Errors After Upgrading it.

**Error**

```
The argument type 'String? Function(GoRouterState)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'FutureOr<String?> Function(BuildContext, GoRouterState)?'
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be late here, but ran into the issue.

The signature or `redirect` has changed and is now

```dart
FutureOr<String?> Function(BuildContext, GoRouterState)? redirect
```

> Notice the `BuildContext` AND the `GoRouterState`.

So in order to fix this, you have to add this argument to your method.

```dart
redirect: (_, GoRouterState state) {
    final loggedIn = AuthService.instance.loginInfo.isLoggedIn;
    final isLogging = state.location == '/login';
    if (!loggedIn && !isLogging) return '/login';
    if (loggedIn && isLogging) return '/stores';
    return null;
}
```

> The fixer here is the `_`, as you don't need the `BuildContext` for what I understand